# If $f(x) = \frac{\sin^{-1} x}{\sqrt{1- x ^2}}$, then evaluate $(1-x^2)f''(x) - xf(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^{-1} x}{\sqrt{1- x ^2}}$

Differentiating the given function, we get

$f'(x) = \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{x\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1-x^2}$

which can also be written as

> $f'(x) = \dfrac{1 + xf(x)}{1-x^2}$

Differentiating this one more time

$f''(x) = \dfrac{(1-x^2)[xf'(x) + f(x)] - [1 + xf(x)](-2x)}{(1-x^2)^2}$

Now the next obvious step is to substitute for $f'(x)$ since we have no $f'(x)$ term in the question.
Which further simplify the equation

$f''(x) = \dfrac{3x[1 + xf(x)] + (1-x^2)f(x)}{(1-x^2)^2}$

Head scratch, I have no idea how to proceed. Possibilities are I have made a mistake above, if so please point out and help me take this ahead.

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for?  Why can't you just substitute and have a complicated answer?

Comment: @MichaelBurr You will be surprised to know that the answer of this question is '1'. I wanna get that '1'

Comment: It seems $(1-x^2) f'(x) - xf(x) = 1$...

Comment: @JeongJinmyeong True, but the OP would like $(1-x^2)f''(x) - xf(x)$, not $(1-x^2) f'(x) - xf(x)$...

Comment: @Martigan I guess that's a typo. and one more comment to the author: if you differentiate $\frac{u}{v}$, you get $\frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$... your 4th equation should have $-$ instead of $+$ in middle.

Comment: @Prateek verify your question.

Comment: Observe, $f(0)=0$ and so does $f''(0)$.  Then, when $x=0$, the expression is $0$, not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

we will differentiate using the implicit definition of $y.$  we have $$y = \frac{\sin^{-1} x}{\sqrt {1- x^2}} \to y^2(1-x^2) = (\sin^{-1} x)^2 \tag 1$$ differentiating once, we have $$ -2xy^2 +2yy'(1-x^2) =\frac 2{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin^{-1} x = 2y$$  diving out by $y, $ you get $$1+xy  =y'(1-x^2) \tag 2 $$ differentiating $(2),$ we have $$xy'  + y = -2xy' +y''(1-x^2) \to (1-x^2)y''-x'y =y+2xy'=y+\frac{2x(1+xy)}{1-x^2}\\=\frac{y(1+x^2)+2x}{1-x^2} $$

Comment: Can you check your final conversion? I don't seem to be able to replicate your not so obvious last step...

Comment: @Martigan, thanks. i guess i was seeing what was not there. i will fix it in am minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has probably a typo, here's how.

Given $$f(x)=\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Using quotient rule,

$$f'(x)=\frac{1+\frac{x\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{1-x^2}$$

Re arranging this we get,

$$(1-x^2)f'(x)=1+x\times \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$(1-x^2)f'(x)=1+xf(x)$$

We get finally, $$(1-x^2)f\color{red}{'}(x)-xf(x)=\color{blue}{1}$$

This is the statement, which gives you the same result as mentioned in comments.